# Would the nature of the marriage influence the rights of men?

Tags: society, culture

It's a human-like race where women are bigger and stronger than men. For the most part, they are matriarchies. Roughly two types of marriages are predominant. In some societies, the man stays with his mother even after marrying a woman. In other societies, the man moves to his wife and her parents. Would that have any influence on whether men had better or worse rights in a society?

Comment: "*the man stays with his mother even after marrying a woman.* Where is his wife?

Comment: In her home. He visits her or she visits him.

Comment: I’ve voted to close as too broad: I can’t think of any way to answer this question that wouldn’t basically be an in depth analysis of the entirety of potential human social norms...

Comment: "*In her home.*"  Is that really "marriage"?

Comment: She can't live with her parents because her Mom's husband lives with his mom.  So she has to live with her mom.   So everybody lives with their mothers.   Sounds Freudian (and maybe even a little Oedipal) to me.

Comment: I too voted to close as "Too broad".  As presently written, this question asks about all of human possibility.  We don't have any estimations of the effects of physical size inversion between men and women compared to current human societies.  Changing such a fundamental characteristic without constraints is just too much.

Comment: Sorry about that. I really didn't want to do that. What could I narrow down? Yeah, it is a marriage. Especially with regard to law, alliances and children.

Comment: I don't see how living in her mother-in-law's roof benefits the daughter. Why would the son get the best of the deal in a matriarchy?

Comment: The daughter can live where she wants and are not forced. The sons have to live with their mother.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you can answer this question by looking at the current real-world situation on Earth.

The status of women depends on two things:

**Economic contribution**

Where the division of labor has the men bringing home all of the food (and money if society has advanced that far), then the women are generally found to be little better off than chattel.

On the other hand, where the men hunt and the women gather (or if the men farm and the women trade), then women have much more status.

So in the case of your race, if the economic contribution of men is is still significant, they will have status; otherwise they will be at the bottom of society.

**Overall equality**

Another factor in the real-world status of women is the disparity of status among men. History seems to indicate that the biggest strides towards equality of men and women came once the men themselves began to be more equal to each other. In those cases where the women are treated like dirt, the vast majority of men are little better off.

So in your fictitious race, if the women are pretty much equal to each other, the men stand a much better chance of having some status as well; they may not have full equality, but they won't be door mats either. If some women are in power and other women have been reduced to serfs, the men will be reduced as well.

**Conclusion**

It will probably not make a whole lot of difference whether the bride moves in with her in-laws, or the groom moves in with his; there are other factors which have much more effect on the status of the weaker sex.

Comment: I disagree with your conclusion, it would make a big difference in relative status for the bride if she lived with the in laws. We have that here, for men, the status of a man living with the inlaws is very low, he's responsible for cooking and cleaning. We have a special word for such a man. For women we have a special name and she is basically a slave to the mother in law and sisters in everything but name.